# How to solve for Aurora Autoscaling MySQL readers in a Rails (4) application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, autoscaling, amazon-aurora

Trying to get our rails (4) application to automatically make use of new auto-scaled Aurora MySQL readers as they are brought online.

We have a Rails 4 web application that currently runs in a static environment on some EC2 instances. The web app is always running. Apache passenger is configured to scale threads up and down, but has a minimum thread pool it keeps up. I really want to make use of Aurora autoscaling, but since the connections are static, its been a challenge. Lets say traffic picks up and hits some threshold, passenger spins up the extra threads needed. All great. But a few minutes later Aurora hits its autoscale thresholds and adds a new reader. None of the threads are actually using the reader because they already have their connections. Restarting the web app would of course use the new reader, but it feels heavy handed and disruptive. I have been playing with RDS Proxy and/or ProxySQL as well as the pool, idle_timeout, & reaping_frequency params on the mysql adapter. Nothing seems to get me to the point where the app can dynamically use (or stop using) the autoscaled readers.

I'm thinking of customizing the adapter to gracefully refresh its connections as a next step but surely there exists an of the shelf solution. We intend to move to Kubernetes in the future which I imagine will solve it due to the ephemeral nature, however I would love to have something working until then.

Can someone that has successfully solved this use case share their solution?

*Update*

In all my testing I was unable to get the connections to move over to the new readers. Once it was establish with an instance, it stayed on that instance. Our web app is static so connections are semi permanent. In no case was an RDS Proxy or ProxySQL middleware able to just start redirecting the  traffic on the same web app connections to new readers. I was able to solve my issue by approaching it from the web server side. We use Phusion passenger and I wrote a poor mans rolling restart script that gracefully removes threads from the pool, lets them finish processing, and die. We haven't started using it yet, but we have options now. We can set it up on a cron to run at regular intervals, or even better, hook into cloud watch events and use lambda to manually run the script when a reader enters or exits the pool.